# A way to exclude specific arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I have a project where I am making a virtual phone and I need to remove specific arrays - but i cannot figure out a way to do it.

Currently I have not found ways to do it yet, I thought about doing it where I only get specific out of the database, but can give som issues with "loading" when opening a chat message. Therefor I want to pull out all the chat from specific user and then remove in the array

My data will look like this when it goes into my jquery

```
var getmessages = [
       {
            sender: "114-5437",
            receiver: "545-3169",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "114-5437",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "999-5435",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "114-5437",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
    ];

$.each(getmessages, function () {
    });
```

So here I want in my each remove all the array that is not the info i need

in this case i want every array elements that has

sender/receiver as 114-5437 and/or sender/receiver as 545-3169

so it should then look something like this in the array

```
var getmessages = [
       {
            sender: "114-5437",
            receiver: "545-3169",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "114-5437",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "114-5437",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
    ];

$.each(getmessages, function () {
    });
```

I hope I explained it well and it make sense. Thank you

Comment: If using `$.each`, the function accepts two parameters - `index` and `value`. The `index` is the index of the object in the array, whereas `value` is the object itself. You can then look at `value.sender` or `value.receiver` and compare to your unwanted numbers, if one of them matches, and the object should be removed, something like `getmessages.splice(index, 1)` to remove it from the array.

Comment: I see, where would i place the .splice? before, after or in the $.each? :)

Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: You can keep an array/set of  `sender` or `receiver` numbers and then compare to your array through `$.each` and delete that index while in loop. for example - `$.each(getmessages, function(index,value){ if(setOfNumbers.has(getmessages[index].sender)){ getmessages.splice(index,1)  }});`

Comment: @ThomasMacédo If you use filter, it will allow you to narrow the use case.  It loops the array once, so it is a simple means of doing translation on an array without changing the base dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what filter is for

```js
var getmessages = [
       {
            sender: "114-5437",
            receiver: "545-3169",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "114-5437",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "999-5435",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
        {
            sender: "545-3169",
            receiver: "114-5437",
            sender_msg: "Hejsa!!!",
            receiver_read: 0,
            date: "2019-04-10 22:14:34"
        },
    ];

console.log(getmessages.filter(item => item.sender === '114-5437' || item.sender === '545-3169' || item.receiver === '114-5437' || item.receiver === '545-3169'));
```

Comment: This works like a charm, haven't used this before. Thank you :) Will look more into this

Comment: I would suggest that your strings you are comparing against are defined as an array.  That way it could be extended in a clean fashion.  Then you can just use:   `arr.includes(item.sender);`